# Set width each element based on sibling text value

Tags: jquery

How can I set width of `.layer-info` based on the value within `.score-java`? A decimal number of `9.8` will be `98%` width, `9` will be `90%` etc. Here is the code:

```
<div class="layer">
    <div class="layer-info">Result</div>
</div>
<span class="score-java">9.8</span>
```

```js
var score = $(".score-java").text();
$(".layer-info").css('width', parseFloat(score) * 10 + '%');
```

I have so far this code, but what if I had multiple layers and I want to set width to each based on its children.

Comment: `based on its children.` or based on the next `span` tag?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8q1rty4e/ by using `width()`.

Answer (score 1):

At that time you have to iterate over each element and set its width,

```
$(".layer .layer-info").css('width', function(){ 
 return parseFloat($(this).closest(".layer").next(".score-java").text()) * 10 + '%'); 
});
```

1. For iterating over each element, you can use the `callBack` function of `.css()`
2. `.closest("selector")` will grab the closest parent of soruce element based on the supplied selector.
3. `.next()` will grab the next element sibling of source element.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bwuy9ee9/)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of multiple `.layer` and `.score-java` elements you could use a loop to retrieve each `.score-java` element then traverse from that to set the width of it's sibling `.layer-info` element, like this:

```
$('.score-java').each(function() {
    $(this).prev('.layer').find(".layer-info").css('width', parseFloat($(this).text()) * 10 + '%');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/eua4L7hh/)

Answer (score 1):

Here my code its works try it.

```
<script> $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.layer-info').each(function() {
  var score = $(this).closest(".layer").next(".score-java").text();
  $('.layer-info').attr("style",'width='+parseFloat(score) * 10+'%;');
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is what the OP already has. They're trying to amend it to work for multiple elements.

Comment: Could you show how to do that so your answer actually does what the OP asks?

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.layer-info').each(function() {
   var score = $(this).closest(".layer").next(".score-java").text();
   $('.layer-info').attr("style",'width='+parseFloat(score) * 10+'%;');
  });
 });
</script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105666/discussion-between-bhupesh-kushwaha-and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 0):

I should make an extra container, in this case `score`, to make it more clearly for yourself.

```js
$(".score").each(function(index) {
  var $self = $(this);
  var score = $self.find(".score-java").text();
  $self.find(".layer-info").css('width', parseFloat(score) * 10 + '%');
  // if you want to expand your score functionality, you can reach every element that you want.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="score">
  <div class="layer">
    <div class="layer-info">Result</div>
  </div>
  <span class="score-java">9.8</span>
</div>
```